# Applying alpha mask to image in Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, png, magick++

I have an image, that has a sequence of two frames. The second frame is supposed to be an alpha mask for the first frame.

Here is an example:

[image]

I've written the following code using Magick++ to split the image into two halves, and apply the alpha mask:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);

    Magick::Image base, mask;
    std::string image;
    
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        image = argv[1];
    }
    else
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Read image
    base.read(image);
    mask = base;

    // Crop out mask and sprite
    base.crop(Magick::Geometry(base.columns() / 2, base.rows(), 0, 0));
    mask.crop(Magick::Geometry(mask.columns() / 2, mask.rows(), mask.columns() / 2, 0));

    // Apply mask
    base.composite(mask, 0, 0, Magick::BlendCompositeOp);

    // Write
    base.write("output.png");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to actually apply this as an alpha mask, rather than just blending it. I cannot find a solution for it anywhere either, at least not for C++.

Comment: I think you need `CopyOpacityCompositeOp`

Answer (score 2):

You should disable the alpha channel on both images and use [CopyOpacity](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#copyopacity) instead of Blend. It also looks like your mask is inverted so you should probably negate it. Below is an example in C++:

```
// Crop out mask and sprite
base.crop(Magick::Geometry(base.columns() / 2, base.rows(), 0, 0));
mask.crop(Magick::Geometry(mask.columns() / 2, mask.rows(), mask.columns() / 2, 0));

// Disable alpha channel
base.matte(false);
mask.matte(false);

// Invert the mask
mask.negate();

// Apply mask
base.composite(mask, 0, 0, Magick::CopyOpacityCompositeOp);
```